# MSBuild, unresolved externals and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2005

I am attempting to use msbuild to build a Visual Studio 2005 solution. The batch file I am using is:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

set VSDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8
set VCVARSALL=%VSDIR%\VC\vcvarsall.bat

call "%VCVARSALL%" x86 && ^
msbuild path\to\my.sln ^
    /v:normal ^
    /p:Configuration=Release ^
    /p:Platform=Win32 ^
    /t:SomeProject:Rebuild

ENDLOCAL
```

Now, SomeProject depends on SomeOtherProject which is all fine and good except I get unresolved externals when building with msbuild:

```
SomeObjFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class SomeClass<class C> C::s_c" (?s_c@C@@0V?$SomeClass@VC@@@@A)
```

The problem is that when I right-click the project in Visual Studio 2005 and select "Rebuild", I don't get any issue with unresolved externals.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong in my invocation of msbuild above?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to use MSBuild for this? VS2005 C++ projects don't use MSBuild. Only 2010 ones do. I'm not sure if that's your problem though, but wouldn't it be more straightforward to call devenv/vcbuild to build the solution from the command line?

Comment: Actually, I'd love to call devenv and be done with it but it doesn't seem to launch *at all*. I previously used devenv.com so I could get output to the console but couldn't get it to launch. Will try with vcbuild.

Comment: Ok, now I remember why: the dependencies don't seem to work when I need to build a specific project.

Comment: Figured out the problem with the msbuild version: the project references were missing.

Comment: You should post that as an answer (and accept it). It might help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem with the msbuild version: the project references were missing. To fix this, right-click on the project in VS and add the references to the missing libraries. Save all projects and Bob's your uncle.